# How can I modify TimePicker to use minutes and seconds instead hour and minutes

Tags: android, timepicker

In my app, the user have to choose minutes and seconds through a TimePicker.

But this component configures hour and minutes by default. How can I modify it?

Comment: are you referring to jQuery timepicker or something else?

Comment: I am referring to Android TimePicker. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to implement your own `MinutesAndSecondsPicker`. `TimePicker` is exclusively tied to hours and minutes.

Comment: Thank you, but for this, do I need to extend the TimePicker class?

Comment: @user1771682: I doubt that will work. You could perhaps clone the source code to `TimePicker`, though.